# Query for Password from SQL Login Authentication

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm new to SQL. I'm trying to extract password from SQL Authentication. Here's what I did:

- First, I tried to create a new login:

  ```
  create login customer with Password = 'pass'
  create user user_1 for login customer
  grant select on Voucher_VIEW_Employee to user_1
  ```
- Then, I have retrieved the login information with the command

  ```
  select * from sys.server_principals
  ```
- And here is the result

[image]

What I want is to be able to access the password of each Login but as you can see, there is no such field in the result.

Is there a more suitable method for this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: [`sys.sql_logins`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-logins-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) provides the `password_hash`. The passwords aren't available.

Comment: As per @HABO. In any secure system, passwords are never available.